# scale_x_date error: date_trans works with objects of class Date only ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set of people registering for a race and I'm plotting a scatterplot using ggplot2.

One axis as ID and one axis as date, to show when people register for the race. The Date variable is already date format so I don't know how to fix this.
Here is my code:

```
ulsample <- sample_n(ultra,1000)

last <- ulsample[ulsample$Date > "2016-10-25",]

plot <- ggplot(last, aes(x=ID,y=Date))+ geom_point(alpha=.6)+facet_grid(~Event)

plot2 <- plot + scale_x_date(date_breaks="months")
```

Then it will show this error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Any idea on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, and sorry in advance if this is super easy :p I'm an R noob.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is you `Date` variable in date format? you may have to convert it using `as.Date()` It would help if you made your question reproducible check out [reprex] .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your ulsample$Date variable is indeed in Date format? Sometimes the variables are actually in character/strong format and it is not obvious by just looking at the values. 
Try inspecting your data frame with "str(ulsample)"

Without seeing your actual data, it will be hard to diagnose the issue. See if you can provide a reproducible example.